# How to explain this number-theoretic seeming “almost coincidence”?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, integer-sequences

For natural numbers $n\geq2$, let $d(n)$ be the number of divisors of $n$, and let
\begin{equation}
g(n)=n\sum_i r_i(p_i-1)
\end{equation}
where $n=\prod_i p_i^{r_i}$ is the factorisation of $n$ as a product of powers of primes.
Define a subsequence $T$ of the natural numbers greater than $1$, by
\begin{equation}
n \in T \iff (n \text{ is odd and } d(n) > \sup \{ d(k): k \text{ odd}, k < n \} ).
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
d(T)=(2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16, 18, 20, 24, 32, 36, 40, 48, 54, 64, 72, 80, 96, 108, 120, 128, 144, \dotsc)
\end{equation}
is [A053640](https://oeis.org/A053640).
Also define a subsequence $S$ of the natural numbers greater than $1$, by
\begin{equation}
n \in S \iff g(n) = \inf \{g(k) : k \geq n \}.
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
S=(2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16, 18, 20, 24, 32, 36, 40, 48, 54, 64, 72, 80, 81, 96, 108, 128, 144, \dotsc).
\end{equation}
So far, these sequences are very similar. Note that $81$ is in $S$ but not in $d(T)$, and $120$ is in $d(T)$ but not in $S$.

Why are they so similar ? So far all I have is this:
\begin{equation}
g \left (\prod_{1\leq i \leq k} a_i \right ) = \sum_{1\leq i \leq k} g(a_i) \prod_{1\leq j \leq k, j \neq i} a_j
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
d(n) = \prod_i (r_i + 1),
\end{equation}
hence
\begin{equation}
g(d(n)) = \sum_i g(r_i + 1) \prod_{j \neq i} (r_j + 1) = \sum_i g(r_i + 1) d \left ( \frac{n}{p_i^{r_i}} \right ).
\end{equation}
Also I can prove that $g(n) \geq n \log_2(n)$, with equality if, and only if, $n$ is a power of $2$. This last fact implies that provided $g(n)$ does not exceed $g(m)$, where $m$ is the least power of $2$ not less than $n$, it is guaranteed that $g(n) < g(a)$, for all $a > m$.

Does this seeming “almost coincidence” have to do with Möbius inversion ? On the other hand, is it not much of a coincidence, as these things go ?

Comment: We can at least show that for any such $d(n) \in T$, $g(d(n)) \leq g(d(nm)) , g(d(n p_i^{r_i})); \forall (n,m)=1, p_i \mid n $....here 2nd doesn't happen always as $g(m)$ is not increasing always.